# How Can I convert REST webservice to SOAP service

Tags: cxf

I am using REST web services in my project, and creating JSON services. But My project is also related to some other project . that will accept only SAOP webservies . 
I want to convert REST json to SAOP webservices .

Please somebody help t over come this problem .

I am using CXF API for creating JSONS.

Comment: i dont think there is any support/tool for automatic conversion between rest and soap. AFAIK you will have to take the pain of writing it yourself !

Answer (score 1):

Your same web service can respond to SOAP (XML) and REST (JSON) request. As stated in comments, you have to make it work (no automation here). Although you don't need to re-write the code. It's just configuration and annotations.

Follow this link - http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-and-jax-ws.html